# @JavascriptInterface not working on android phone v4.2.2

Tags: javascript, java, android

Am facing an issue with @JavascriptInterface . When i try to run on android v4.4.2 below code works fine(able to call the below method from JavaScript using window.Android.getAlbumList)

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String getAlbumsList() {
    ArrayList<String> albumList = new ArrayList<>();
    ContentResolver musicResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
```

but when i try to run it in v4.2.2 it is able to compile but the JavaScript code is not able to call Native(java) code .

My build.gradle file:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pd45844.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

Does compileSdkVersion , minSdkVersion ,targetSdkVersion causing me a problem .
Any idea on this ?